# Specific Row at the top line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a table in SQl database which shows the result the way below:

```
   ID    Name     value

    1    Chips     100

    2    Chocolate   50

    3    Ice Cream   200

    4    Burger      40
```

but I want to display it like in this way:

```
        Name     value

        Chocolate    50

        Chips       100

        Ice Cream   200

        Burger      40
```

how can I do this in sql server?

Comment: What is the logic for this sorting?

Comment: Always wants to show the Chocolate item at the top of the row.

Comment: whatever the names are in the database in the output it always shows the Chocolate at the top line then rest of others

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ID` to do the sorting like below

```
ORDER BY CASE ID 
    WHEN 2 THEN 1 
    WHEN 1 THEN 2 
    WHEN 3 THEN 3 
    WHEN 4 THEN 4
    ELSE 5
    END
```

If there is dynamic rows (lot of rows), you can use same like below

```
ORDER BY CASE ID 
        WHEN 2 THEN 1 
        ELSE 2
        END
```

The else part will take care of the rest of the rows.

Comment: what should i do when there are lots of Name?

Comment: @SaNa3819 I have updated my answer. It is left to you which column to use for comparison.

Comment: but in this case chips go to bottom but it should be in second line

Comment: You wanted only Chocolate to be at the top, you can add any number of WHEN along with CASE. Check my latest update to the first query. That will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` in `ORDER BY` to make sure the record with `name = 'Chocolate'` comes first and the rest is sorted by `ID`.

```
select name, value
from table1
order by case name
   when 'Chocolate' then -1
   else ID
end
```

Comment: but in this case chips go to bottom but it should be in second line

Comment: Based on what? You can add more conditions to case if you need to.

Comment: i want the chocolate row at top line then wants the other name according to their ID.

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer now. And please specify all the requirements in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 1 ORDER BY name =  'Chocolate' DESC
```